# QML Button assign arrow shortcut

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

Is it possible to assign an arrow shortcut to a QML Button? With the Action item I can assign a shortcut by string or by KeySequence (https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls2-action.html#shortcut-prop), but how can I assign a shortcut of an arrow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [Shortcut](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-shortcut.html) ,like this :

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Shortcut")

    Button {
        id: button
        x: 199
        y: 144
        width: 190
        height: 105
        text: qsTr("Button")
        Shortcut
        {
            sequence:"Up" // "Down" , "Right" ,"Left"
            onActivated:button.clicked()
        }

        onClicked:
        {
            console.log("Up Arrow")
        }
    }


}
```

**"Up" <kbd>↑</kbd>, "Down" <kbd>↓</kbd>, "Right"<kbd>→</kbd> ,"Left"<kbd>←</kbd>** **used for Arrows in keyboard**.

Comment: Thank you, it works! Where did you find that the text "Up" is associated with the up arrow?

Comment: @Fausto01 your welcome, the up arrow means "Up", as the control key is "Ctrl", I understand it from widgets. I used it before in c++ and widgets

Comment: @Fausto01 you can use `StandardKey` instead. Look at [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-shortcut.html#details)